# Use update_post_meta to change one field that has a duplicate key and value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to allow users to add past jobs they worked at and for. I would like to know how to update only one Job Title (key) even if it has a duplicate field with the same exact Key and Value.

Example.

```
jobTitle => 'Nike'
jobTitle => 'Nike'

update_post_meta($ID,'jobTitle', Google );

jobTitle => 'Nike'
jobTitle => 'Google'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me it is not possible to have exact two key for one post.

You can store it by creating your custom table but it will not store your data with using the update_post_meta.